# Mulit level dropdown select (multiple times on one page)

Tags: html, css, blazor

Is it possible to build a multi level overflow dropdown select (multiple times on one page) only with html and css like the one from the image?
[image]

I tried it with some good solutions in Javascript. But blazor says no, and this is way to complex for me.

Comment: Yes it is.  What does your data set look like?  What have you tried to do?  In your rejection of the answer provided you said "no overflow/overlay".  What other pertinent information have you missed out in your question?

Comment: In my question I asked for overflow. Maybe that's the wrong word for what I mean. When I click on an item of the dropdown, the visible new list should be visible "over" the elements down there. With the solution Henry wrote, the elements will pushed downwards. What did I tried? Many dropdown css menus I found. But the "overlay" or what ever it's called, will not work.

Comment: In the image you've shown it appears that when you "expand" a node, everything moves down to make space for that node's sub-nodes.  And visa-versa when you toggle the node closed, but you seem to be saying you want the expended node to appear as some sort of popup over the following nodes.  Also, it would be helpful to see your data classes that are to be displayed?

Comment: It's OK. Thx for trying. I find a solution with position absolute. But to answering you, on the pic you only see the whole dropdown. So, everything "behind" or down them is not visible for you. Because, I asked for a dropdown like that. :)

Comment: NP, but as you now have a solution, please close the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well it possible with pure html and css, but i don't know if it still work when involve blazor (i don't know anything about C#), but let try anyway.

I'm assuming it acted like a tree nav from look of the image. So basically, the structure is simple, just a checkbox, a label and then a div with whatever you want inside to be show when parent's text had been clicked. I'm not good at explaining thing, so see code below for more insight.

```css
*[class*="level_"] {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown_main {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.child_level {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
label, span {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
input:checked + label + *, input:checked + label + * > div {
    display: block;
}
.child_level .child_level {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="level_1">
    <input id="level1_item1" type="checkbox" style="visibility:hidden">
    <label for="level1_item1" class="dropdown_main">Level 1</label>
    <div class="child_level">
        <div class="level_2">
            <input id="level2_item1" type="checkbox" style="visibility:hidden">
            <label for="level2_item1">Level 2</label>
            <label for="level1_item1" class="child_level">Level 3</label>
        </div>

        <div class="level_2">
            <input id="level2_item2" type="checkbox" style="visibility:hidden">
            <label for="level2_item2">Level 2</label>
            <div class="child_level">
                <div class="level_3">
                    <input id="level3_item1" type="checkbox" style="visibility:hidden">
                    <label for="level3_item1">Level 3</label>
                    <label for="level1_item1" class="child_level">Level 4</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 15px;">Content Below</div>
```

Again, i don't know what kind of icon you may use so i don't include it within the code, but you can toggle it with the checkbox status like with the content anyway, so hope this help.

Comment: I tried. But this solution has no overflow/overlay. So the following content will push down. That's no option for me.

Comment: @StephanMayer I've edited to make it overlay like normal select box (though it need some more css to make it look nicer).